# Can I use normal metal electrical box for outdoor low voltage installation?

Tags: electrical, outdoor, low-voltage

Installing a few PoE IP camera under the eave, I am trying to put a electric box to contain the network cable connection and to prevent vandalism.

As I have a few normal interior metal boxes lying around, would those be considered ok to install in a damp location for low voltage device? (metal box like this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Raco-2-Gang-Gray-Metal-Interior-New-Work-Standard-Square-Celing-Wall-Electrical-Box/3129657 )

These electric box is used only for vandalize prevention.. I am not relying on that for the weather proofing. The ethernet cable has it's own water tight connector and I will be painting these boxes just to make it rust slower.

My concern is would that be something against the code? Really not sure about the low voltage related code. Anyone knows about it?

Comment: Why do you think an interior-type metal box will hold up to vandalism?  They aren't really rated for any sort of physical damage to begin with...

Comment: My thought is more about it provides a relatively solid base for mounting, and it would still take quite a bit of beating to break it. The IP Cam is also metal housing, from what I can see of similar thickness.

Well. if they are determined, nothing is vandal proof..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only code problem is the UL listing. I am pretty sure those are indoor rated only and not even for damp locations.

Also, unless protected from rain, it would be considered a wet location, not damp.

Comment: Got it. Will change to outdoor ones then.